# Is ASP.Net Core session state reliable enough to store a critical token?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-state

I am trying to implement a read-only demo mode into my application that allows someone to login as an existing user but doesn't allow them to persist any changes.

I have the functionality working but I'm struggling to figure out where to store the "read only token". Currently if a user clicks demo mode on the login page they are logged in and I add a read-only claim to the user claims. This initially works fine and everything works as expected.

The issue is if the user is inactive for 20 minutes or so, ASP refreshes the user and regenerates the claims but doesn't include the read-only claim because it isn't stored in the database. It's also not possible for me to re-add the claim here because at this point I don't know whether the user was initially signed in as read-only or not. This means the user is now signed in normally and has permission to change anything.

I was thinking about storing the read-only token in session storage instead of claims but after reading the docs it sounds like session also gets refreshed after 20 minutes and that you shouldn't rely on session for site functionality.

Is session the right place for this? If for any reason the user ends up signed in without this token (as happens with claims), they suddenly have full access to delete anything.

At this point I'm considering creating a dedicated demo user that maps to the same ID as a real user so that I can persist the fact that it is read-only but I would like to know if there is a reliable way to achieve this with my original method.

Comment: Can you add a login type field to the user's status, and judge whether he has various permissions based on this status.

Comment: What do you mean to the user's status? Do you mean in the database? The problem with this is that the same account could be signed into in two places, one being the real user and the other being the demo user so it really needs to be some kind of session token.